# comparing values of a column with a variable and make new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, valueerror

I have a dataframe like this :

```
           Patch  Last reward  First reward  Difference    Name  Block_No.
group_id                                                                 
1             3          0.0           0.0         0.0  XYZ          1
2             4         43.0          54.0        11.0  XYZ          1
3             5          0.0           0.0         0.0  XYZ          2
4             6         40.0          65.0        25.0  XYZ          2
5             7          0.0           0.0         0.0  XYZ          3
6             0          0.0           0.0         0.0  XYZ          3
```

I want to create a  new column called 'Rep_rate' based on the following condition:
if block_no. = 1 and if patch = 3 , then Rep_rate = 4 , else Rep_rate = 0.

I tried doing this :

```
if (df_last['Block_No.']) == 1:
            for i in range (len(df_last)):
                if df_last['Patch'][i] == 1: 
                    rep = 8
                else:
                    rep = 0
                df_last['Rep_Rate'] = rep

if (df_last['Block_No.']) == 2:
                for i in range (len(df_last)):
                    if df_last['Patch'][i] == 1: 
                        rep = 4
                    else:
                        rep = 0
                    df_last['Rep_Rate'] = rep

 if (df_last['Block_No.']) == 3:
                for i in range (len(df_last)):
                    if df_last['Patch'][i] == 1: 
                        rep = 8
                    else:
                        rep = 0                            
                    df_last['Rep_Rate'] = rep
```

However when i try this i get the following error :

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Can you explain how you compute the column RR, please?

Comment: yes sir, i want to see if the value for block is 1 and for patch is 3 then rr wud be 4, if value of block is 1 , patch = 2 , then rr = 0.

Comment: Are these defined in some dictionary or dataframe? How are these pairings determined?

Comment: i will edit the question for better understanding, sorry .

Comment: i have edited the question , do let me knw if u can help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the logic you are using to populate the RR column, but one approach might be:

```
df['RR'] = 0
if (df['Block'] == 1).all():
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        if row['Patch'] == 3:
            df.loc[i,'RR'] = 4 # note using df.loc to directly edit the dataframe
elif (df['Block'] == x).all():
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        if row['Patch'] == y:
            df.loc[i,'RR'] = z
# more if statements as needed
```

Replace `x`, `y`, and `z` with whatever values you need.

The issue you are having is with `if df["Block"] == 1`. The code `df["Block"] == 1` results in a boolean Series of True/False for whether or not each value in the Series is equal to 1. Using an if statement against a Series is not supported because the meaning is ambiguous. Pandas provides `ser.any()` and `ser.all()` for unambiguous boolean evaluation. EG

```
if (df["Block"] ==1).all():
    # more code ...
```

would evaluate the code in the `if` statement if all of the values in the Block column were equal to 1.

Comment: ok this makes a lot of sense, thank u, but then cud u help me how can i use the values of all rows of a column and check it with a condition , as == doesnt work here.

Comment: You would need `if (df['Block'] == 1).all()`. I have edited my answer to reflect what I think you mean :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `df.query()` for this.
For example:
Let's say this is your data frame

```
          Patch     Block_No.
                                                                
             3         1
             4         1
             5         2
             6         2
             7         3
             0         3
```

```
# add a new column and set values to 0
df['Rep_rate'] = 0

# run query and store index on a list
idx = df.query('Patch == 3 & Block_No. == 1').index.tolist()

# update values in Rep_rate column using this list
df.loc[idx, 'Rep_rate '] = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to alter the logic (I don't totally understand either).  However, looping on rows is not great.  So...

**Try:**

```
import pandas as pd

# create a test dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Block_No.': [1,1,2,2,3,3], 'Patch': [3,4,5,6,7,0], })

# create a function to return 8 or 0 depending on the values of 'Block' and 'Patch'
def fillRep_rate(block, patch):
    if (block == 1) & (patch == 3):
        return 4
#     more options to return other values if required...
#     elif (block == 2) & (patch == 4):
#         return 5
#     elif (block == 3) & (patch == 5):
#         return 6
    else:
        return 0

# create a new column called 'RR' and populate with the value returned from the function above
df['Rep_rate'] = df.apply(lambda x: fillRep_rate(x['Block_No.'], x['Patch']), axis=1)

print(df)
```

**Outputs:**

```
    Block_No.   Patch   Rep_rate
0   1           3       8
1   1           4       0
2   2           5       0
3   2           6       0
4   3           7       0
5   3           0       0
```